# How can I find all the dependencies for an executable?

Tags: windows, dll, executable

What programs/applications can I run on a Windows executable to find all the DLLs that it depend on or uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic one is the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

It lists all the statically-imported dlls (and the functions that are actually used) and the delayload dlls; also, running the program it can provide you a list of the dynamically-loaded (as in LoadLibrary) dlls and the used entrypoints (if retrieved via GetProcAddress).